# Separate releases running on same device?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've created an android app and installed it on my device.
Now I have changed the name and the icon for this app.

Is it possible to install this next to the "previous" app ? 
When I try this it overwrites the previous one.
(I would prefer not to change the package name(s) since want to do this more then once).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible the way you want. Name of application is irrelevant (it is just for humans). Package name (`package` attribute of `<manifest>` is what matters, so you need to name packages of your both builds differently to make this happen. There's no other way.

Comment: ok thanks !  <br>
The app is a client branded app . <br>
How would go about handling your source code in these situations ?
Making exact copies of the app just seems so overkill ? 
refactoring everything for every single release also not ideal i think?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the package name.